# SFLOW :: My Throughput Calculations Need a Constant Offset?

Tags: sflow

Hello Networking Jedi Masters,

I recently set up vFlow, an open source sFlow collector from Verizon Digital. 
 The collector works great, is quite stable, and easy to manage.  I can’t say enough nice things about it.

But there is a weird hitch about which I wanted to ask this forum.  Once I got my sFlow statistics, I wanted to know the throughput of my network applications, which seems quite reasonable, right?  To estimate the total number of bytes sent in one sampled flow, I have code which calculates the following:

```
( Size of Sampled Packet Payload )  *  ( Sampling Rate )
```

In sFlow, these statistics would be:

```
( Packet.L3.TotalLen )  *  ( Sample.SamplingRate )
```

In other words, if vFlow samples a packet with 1,500 bytes in its IP payload, and my sampling rate is 1/64, then I’ll assume the entire flow is:

```
( 1500 bytes )  *  (  64 packets in this flow )  =  96,000 bytes in this flow
```

Simple.  But when I did very basic measurement tests with iPerf, I noticed that this calculation was always off.  And always off by a ***consistent*** amount.  Doing a little reverse engineering by watching packet sizes, sampling rate, and actual number of bytes sent, I realized that the formula I actually need is this:

```
( Packet.L3.TotalLen )  *  ( Sample.SamplingRate )  *  (  Some constant  )  =  Total bytes sent
```

Hmm.

I did a lot of experimenting on this, playing with packet sizes.  (My production environment uses 1/64 as our universal sampling rate, so I didn’t bother varying that.)  For those who are curious, here are the results I found:

```
Packet Payload
(Bytes)          Constant
==============================
100              3.456997168
300              4.647359333
500              4.971690001
1000             5.230202893
1500             5.346555979
```

If you graph this, the line approaches ~5.35.  I ran hundreds of individual tests for each packet size, and the results were extremely consistent; vFlow is very stable.

I don’t mind hardwiring this mysterious constant into my code to calculate total bytes sent.  But I’m completely mystified ***why the constant is needed at all.***  Shouldn’t my original formula have been enough to estimate total throughput?  What could that constant signify?  Is this an sFlow thing?  Or perhaps a vFlow (mis)configuration that I’ve overlooked?

Any thoughts are wildly appreciated.  Thanks!

PS: The version of vFlow I am using is [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/vdms/vflow/), I opted for the Docker container version of vFlow.  More general info about vFlow is [here](https://github.com/VerizonDigital/vflow)